# How to listen for a "div created" event?

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

I need to know when a `div` element is added to the page.  Anytime, anywhere, as a child at any depth of the document tree.

```js
const { body } = document;
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => console.log(node));
    }
  }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(body, config);
```

I run this code via an extension immediately upon page navigation.  As Google search results are loading, this doesn't log the creation of any of them.  Only a handful of divs in the header and footer, and a couple scripts.  I need to be notified as soon as any and every `div` element appears on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```js
observer.observe(body, config);
```

This was wrong, it has to be:

```js
observer.observe(document, config);
```